# How to run PHP code without waiting for the response?

Tags: php, curl

I have a website (Site A) where visitors arrive every day. Site A is only tracking the user and redirecting them to Site B, when it's done.

I would like a PHP based solution which allows me to start a specific task on the server and redirect the visitor right after it has started. Basically I would not want my users to wait while my PHP scripts (which are taking like 3-4 sec to complete) are finishing their work.

It is very much essential to redirect the user as soon as possible. I have thought about Cronjobs, but it's not good because it can only run specific times, as far as I know. Also cURL isn't good, because it needs to wait the server to finish loading (as I know).

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a CURL call. There is a thing in php called ignore_user_abort(). Combine that with set_time_limit() and you will be able to create a PHP script that will continue running even if curl request is cancelled.